# how change the RadDataPager Page# From CodeBehind (server-side)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, paging, radlistview, raddatapager

hi my dear friends :
how can i change the RadDataPager(telerik) Page# From CodeBehind (server-side)?
mean change the current page to another!

i can find it like below :

```
var raddatapager = (RadListViewImages).FindControl("RadDataPager1") as RadDataPager;
```

but now how can i change the page?

```
raddatapager .????????????
```

i couldn't find a way from it's demo!

thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: i did n't try any code , i do n't know what code should i try! there is no servers-side help about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FireCommand method to force a page change. Simply pass in "Page" as the CommandName and the page number as the CommandArgument:

```
var pager = RadListViewImages.FindControl("RadDataPager1") as RadDataPager;
if (pager != null)
{
    int pageNumber = GetNewPageNumber();
    pager.FireCommand("Page", pageNumber.ToString());
}
```

Other options for the CommandArgument are "First", "Next", "Prev", and "Last" to go to the first page, the next page, the previous page, or the last page, respectively.

See the [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/datapager-overview.html) for details.