# how to select last page on a radlistview datapager

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a radlistview which has the datapager enabled...

But when I launch the website it currently loads the first datapage on the listview (i.e the first page of comments). Is there a way to change this so that it opens the last page?

Here is the current radlistview...

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="RadListViewComments" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceComments" PageSize="5">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="RadListView RadListViewFloated RadListView_Default">
            <div class="rlvFloated rlvAutoScroll">
                <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </div>
            </div>
            <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server">
                <Fields>
                    <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric" />
                </Fields>
            </telerik:RadDataPager>

        </div>
```

```
    <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="rlvI" style="width: 700px; margin-bottom: 50px" margin-right: 100%>
                    <asp:Label ID="ownerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("owner") %>' /> &nbsp - &nbsp
                    <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("commentdate")%>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="commentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>' />
                </div>
   </ItemTemplate>

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="RadListView RadListView_Default">
            <div class="rlvEmpty">
                There are no previous comments.</div>
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
 </telerik:RadListView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind you can fire a command event with the "Last" argument on PageLoad to force it to go to the last page.

See

- [how change the RadDataPager Page# From CodeBehind (server-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051134/how-change-the-raddatapager-page-from-codebehind-server-side)
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/datapager-overview.html